# EF Code First not creating tables

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbset

I am using Entity Framework 5 (4.4.0) for .NET 4

I have a model created in code, as I did with several others. When I run my application, it creates the database, but does not create any tables. After that the application, exits with no error message - even in debug mode. I have no clue what the problem is.

Is any one else having this problem?

Is the order important when creating the context class?

```
public DbSet<Order> Orders ...
public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails ...
```

Or can it be in any order?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 4.1 Code First not creating tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250297/entity-framework-4-1-code-first-not-creating-tables)

Answer (score 0):

what initialization strategy are you using ?

```
Database.SetInitializer(your strategy);
```

you have to tell code first how you want to create your DB

have a look at

[Entity Framework 4.1 Code First not creating tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250297/entity-framework-4-1-code-first-not-creating-tables)